# FileNotFoundException while deploying pyspark job on YARN cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Trying to submit the below test.py Spark app on a YARN cluster with the below command

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=./venv/venv/bin/python spark-submit --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./venv/venv/bin/python --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --archives venv#venv test.py
```

Note: I am not using local mode, but trying to use the python3.7 site-packages under the virtualenv used for building the code in PyCharm. The virtualenv provides the custom app packages that are not provided as cluster services

This is how the Python project structure looks along with the contents of venv directory

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 schakrabarti nobody 225908565 Feb 26 13:07 venv.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 schakrabarti nobody      1313 Feb 26 13:07 test.py
drwxr-xr-x 6 schakrabarti nobody      4096 Feb 26 13:07 venv
drwxr-xr-x 3 schakrabarti nobody      4096 Feb 26 13:07 venv/bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 schakrabarti nobody      4096 Feb 26 13:07 venv/share
-rw-r--r-- 1 schakrabarti nobody        75 Feb 26 13:07 venv/pyvenv.cfg
drwxr-xr-x 2 schakrabarti nobody      4096 Feb 26 13:07 venv/include
drwxr-xr-x 3 schakrabarti nobody      4096 Feb 26 13:07 venv/lib
```

Getting the same error of File does not exist - pyspark.zip (as shown below)

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://hostname-nn1.cluster.domain.com:8020/user/schakrabarti/.sparkStaging/application_1571868585150_999337/pyspark.zip
```

Please refer to my comments added on Spark-10795: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10795

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if I misunderstood the problem, but according to

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=./venv/venv/bin/python spark-submit --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./venv/venv/bin/python --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --archives venv#venv test.py
```

you use Yarn cluster, but in your test.py

```
#test.py
import json
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

if __name__ == "__main__":
  spark = SparkSession.builder \
   .appName("Test_App") \
   .master("spark://gwrd352n36.red.ygrid.yahoo.com:41767") \
   .config("spark.ui.port", "4057") \
   .config("spark.executor.memory", "4g") \
   .getOrCreate()

  print(json.dumps(spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll(), indent=4))

  spark.stop()
```

you try to connect to Spark standalone cluster

```
spark://gwrd352n36.red.ygrid.yahoo.com:41767
```

So, it can be a problem

Comment: That is not the issue as I forgot to replace the actual hostname with the dummy hostname. I am using the master URL same as what is returned from `sc.getConf.getAll`

Comment: Do you mean that using spark:// prefix is for standalone cluster? Are you suggesting to use hdfs://?

Comment: Yes, spark:// is only for standalone cluster.

Actually, you don't need to specify master in code if you use -master yarn in start command.

According the https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls you need to specify HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR location

Comment: Specifying `spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname` and `spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address` can also help.

Comment: Used `.master("yarn-cluster")`. Still facing the same issue.